# compose extend file results in a validation error

Tags: docker-compose

Hi I have two compose files, one describing how to organize services (docker-compose.yml) and the other to build images (docker-compose.build.yml) of the same services. I am not sure if splitting the single file this way makes sense, but I just discovered this feature and want to experiment it.

My point is from a single file when I use `docker-compose build web`, everything work fine.
When I split the file in the 2 defined above and using
`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.build.yml build web`
I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Validation failed, reason(s):
web.build.args contains null, which is an invalid type, it should be a string, or a number
```

The single file looks like (single docker-compose.yml):

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    image: registry.private:5000/mycompany/web:dev
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
    - "9000:9000"
    environment:
    - SQL_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/mydb
    build:
      context: ./applications/web
      args:
      - VCS_REF
      - BUILD_DATE
      - http_proxy
```

Once split, the first file docker-compose.yml looks like:

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    image: registry.private:5000/mycompany/web:dev
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
    - "9000:9000"
    environment:
    - SQL_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/mydb
```

And the second file docker-compose.build.yml looks like:

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./applications/web
      args:
      - VCS_REF
      - BUILD_DATE
      - http_proxy
```

This simple example does not work in my experiment. I want to be confident in the feature before going further. Such as specializing the compose file for our CI.

If anyone can tell me where I am mistaken. Thanks.

docker-compose version 1.6.2, build 4d72027

Docker version 1.10.3, build 20f81dd

---

Using PyYAML it happens the (services.???)web.build.args is an array and not what docker-compose claim it be a (contains) null.

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from yaml import load, dump
>>> document = """
... services:
...   web:
...     build:
...       context: ./applications/web
...       args:
...       - VCS_REF
...       - BUILD_DATE
...       - http_proxy
...       - app_path=target/universal/web-0.1-SNAPSHOT.tgz
... """
>>> print load(document)
{'services': {'web': {'build': {'args': ['VCS_REF', 'BUILD_DATE', 'http_proxy', 'app_path=target/universal/web-0.1-SNAPSHOT.tgz'], 'context': './applications/web'}}}}
```

Comment: Looks like a bug. I would try it with the latest released version (1.8.1) and if it's still broken open an issue on github

Comment: My first guess was me doing something erroneous. Works with compose 1.8.1, thank @dnephin.

Comment: @dnephin, you should put that in an answer so that Yohann can select it and give you your rightfully earned points :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug. I would try it with the latest released version (1.8.1) and if it's still broken open an issue on github.